# WebSocket to Ldap

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, ldap

I am trying to etablish a websocket connection to an ldap server. That I can simply send binary data to and receive binary data.
But it fails on the handshake whatever I do.

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ads.de:PORT")
```

Yours sincerely
Skeec

Answer (score 1):

Web sockets is a specific protocol, like HTTP, and it has "nothing" to do with a TCP/UPD socket. 
You cannot connect with web-sockets to an LDAP-server, let alone connect to a different domain without receiving the appropriate CORS http-headers (and the browser supporting CORS).

You need to write a proxy WebSocket server application so that you can communicate with the LDAP-directory. You cannot do it in JavaScript (unless you want to use an ActiveX object, which will be incompatible with non-Microsoft browsers (and newer Microsoft browsers).

You better do it with plain-old AJAX with an asynchronous handler.
You don't need WebSockets for that, you're only wasting bandwidth.

Comment: I was using a Rest API with ldapjs and restify, but when I had to handle 200+ entries coming back to ldapjs I was just pushing the json entry to an array until res.end and then sent the array back. This leads inevitably to a longer runtime, therefore I came up with streams, whether its websocket or just node streams. Do you think this is unpracticable, due to bandwidth? :/